# Java - JSP templates in database

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm building 3 websites based on Java and Spring.

I also need another website to manage those 3 websites templates.

I have question - do you have knowledge about building websites in Java with external site templates - whose templates (maybe JSP files) are placed in external folder from Tomcat ?

I need any mechanism, that will be able to change templates in all 3 websites without need to deploy again application andIi want that those templates will be outside Java war.

Answer (score 0):

You can referee any folder in tomcat, even those who are in a different directory.

Are you sure you like to put them into a database? You loose advatages you had from a version-controll-system like svn/git/cvs?

Maybe the Continues-Delivery would match your needs, its like a release but about 10-20 minutes after committing changes to svn/git/cvs.